# Open CTI runApex() with multiple parameters

Tags: opencti

I am attemping to link our CTI call center calls to a custom object that is a child of Case.  The intent is to create a record that contains the Case Id and the CTI Call Id so that our data analysis tools can link comprehensive call and case data for reporting purposes.

To accomplish this, I am trying to use sforce.interaction.runApex() and passing in the name of a web service, method, parameters, and callback.  This works fine when I am only passing the Case Id (one parameter) to the web service method, like so:

```
sforce.interaction.runApex('GlobalWebServicesEx', 'CreateCTILogs',
    'caseid='+cid, callback);
```

Where cid is the Case Id filled from a parsed JSON string returned by `getPageInfo(getPageInfoCallback)`.

What I really want to do is pass both the Case ID and the CTI Call ID into my web service method, like so:

```
sforce.interaction.runApex('GlobalWebServicesEx', 'CreateCTILogs', 
    'caseid='+cid, 'callid='+call, callback);
```

where call is the variable that holds the call id.  I have tried different variations of passing the two string parameters to my web service method but it fails every time.  I can't seem to get the correct syntax or find an example of passing two parameters into a web service using the runApex() function.  If anyone knows how to do this, please show me an example.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_runapex.htm) specifies, you must use a standard URL query string syntax:

```
sforce.interaction.runApex('GlobalWebServicesEx', 'CreateCTILogs', 
    'caseid='+encodeURIComponent(cid)+'&callid='+encodeURIComponent(call), callback);
```

Note that you should always use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to avoid accidental escaping issues with special characters.

Comment: This worked!  Thanks so much.  You're a life-saver!